# iOS FTP Upload with SCRFTPRequest on ARC

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, automatic-ref-counting

Hy Everybody, i am using SCRFTPRequest, https://github.com/Hackmodford/SCRFTPRequest to upload a file on a FTP server, i've used it before, it worked great, but now i have a project that is with ARC, the API was recoded to ARC a couple of days ago.

I have a crash, i don't know why, it crashes without any error message after startRequest, the whole function gets executed, including startUploadRequest. I really don't know why it crashes. I've tested on iPAD 1 with 5.0 and iPad 3 with 6.1.

I've tried with other files, same problem, the file is created on the FTP server with the correct name but the size is 0 Kb.

```
filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Spiriva Mentiones Legales" ofType:@"pdf"];
SCRFTPRequest *ftpRequest = [[SCRFTPRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"ftp://ftp.belersoft.ro/"]
                                                  toUploadFile:filePath];             
ftpRequest.username = @"user";
ftpRequest.password = @"pass";

ftpRequest.delegate = self;
ftpRequest.customUploadFileName = [modifiedPathWithXLS lastPathComponent];

[ftpRequest startRequest];
```

I have implemented all the Delegate Callbacks, only will ftpRequestWillStart gets called

Comment: Did you find any thing around ? I am also using SCRFTpRequest library and I am having the same issue, My file is also getting uploaded but with size 0 bytes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case anyone else having the 'zero-byte file upload' issue that needs help with this, try replacing

`[ftpRequest startRequest];`
with

```
[ftpRequest startAsynchronous];
```

And add the following delegate method to your code:

`- (void)ftpRequest:(SCRFTPRequest *)request didChangeStatus:(SCRFTPRequestStatus)status`

(note the difference between the method name versus the one listed in the SCRFTPRequest docs.)

I'm not familiar enough with this library yet to be comfortable changing the library itself, but adjusting the delegate method name and using asynchronous worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

use [ftpResuest startAsynchronous]

Comment: Please elaborate the answers.. Answers are expected to be of high standards

Comment: Please be more precise. Otherwise, your answer is of little help.